# Python как исправить ошибку UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 98-99: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, unicode, кодировка

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-


import json,time,urllib,sys,codecs
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import traceback;#uotput error
from jsonpath_ng import parse, jsonpath
from urllib.request import urlopen






user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'

url = 'https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/per-article/en.wikipedia/all-access/all-agents/Alexander_SkarsgГҐrd/daily/2015010100/2020022500'

request = urllib.request.Request(url,headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})
try:

    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    print ("response: "+str(response))
    html = response.read()
    #print (html)
    #res = json.loads(response.text)
    a = json.loads(html)
    #print ('+_+_+_+_+')
    #print ('a: '+str(a))
```

> 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 98-99: ordinal not in range(128)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "1.py", line 25, in 
>       response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
>       return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
>       response = self._open(req, data)
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\urllib\request.py", line 543, in _open
>       '_open', req)
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1360, in https_open
>       context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1317, in do_open
>       encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\http\client.py", line 1244, in request
>       self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\http\client.py", line 1255, in _send_request
>       self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\http\client.py", line 1122, in putrequest
>       self._output(request.encode('ascii'))
>   UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 98-99: ordinal not in range(128)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\backend.py", line 1154, in wrapper
>       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\backend.py", line 1141, in wrapper
>       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\backend.py", line 1213, in _execute_prepared_user_code
>       exec(statements, global_vars)
>     File "1.py", line 41, in 
>       data = json.load(urlopen(url))
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
>       return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
>       response = self._open(req, data)
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\urllib\request.py", line 543, in _open
>       '_open', req)
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1360, in https_open
>       context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1317, in do_open
>       encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\http\client.py", line 1244, in request
>       self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\http\client.py", line 1255, in _send_request
>       self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\http\client.py", line 1122, in putrequest
>       self._output(request.encode('ascii'))
>   UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 98-99: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: мне кажется, надо сменить кодировку на `utf-8`